# Boolean if variables have all similarities

Tags: javascript, numbers, boolean

I have 2 numbers and I would like to compare them. If all number B appears in A = true
else = false

I've tried this but it's still returning True when B has a number that doesn't exist in A

```
  if (A >= B)
    return true
  else
    return false
```

ex:

```
    A = 98765
    B = 8759
    A >= B // True
    
    A = 154
    B = 154
    A >= B // True

    A = 875
    B = 8756
    A >= B // False

    A = 1111
    B = 112
    A >= B //output: True // expected output: False because don't have 2 in A
```

Comment: Well, you're just comparing *numbers*, *numerically*. Thousand one hundred eleven is larger than hundred twelve.

Comment: is 1111 greater than 112? Yes. So, this works as intended. Why would you you expect the simple `>` operator to work for obscure requirement like *"If all number B appears in A, then return true"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following steps:

1. convert each number into a string with `toString()`
2. convert each string into its individual characters with `.split('')`
3. check for every character in `B` if it is included in the characters of `A`

```
const aChars = A.toString().split('')
const bChars = B.toString().split('')

return bChars.every(c => aChars.includes(c))
```